# Fetching single row, single column with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a mysql query that targets a single column in a single row

```
"SELECT some_col_name FROM table_name WHERE user=:user"
```

After I execute the statement `$stmt->execute();` how do I get this single cell directly placed into a variable with no loops? In other words how to get

```
from $stmt->execute();

to $col_value = 100;
```

I tried the 2 below, but neither worked.. The column is number 4 in the original table, but I'm assuming since in my select statement I'm selecting it only, it should be 1 when I specify the parameter for fetchColumn.

```
$col_value = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$col_value = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to do it in as few lines as possible.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Are you sure it's returning any rows?

```
$stmt->fetchColumn()
```

is correct way to fetch a single value, so either you probably didn't bind the :user parameter or it simply returned no rows.

Comment: Thanks all, it turned out to be something with the database itself. I knew it should have been working

Answer (score 13):

```
$sql='SELECT some_col_name FROM table_name WHERE user=?';

$sth=$pdo_dbh->prepare($sql);
$data=array($user);

$sth->execute($data);

$result=$sth->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, $number_of_column);
```

Comment: Why is this way what you recommend?  What is it doing?

Comment: @KevinPanko: it's the same thing but I like this way, it normalize the code in my model, calling fetch() or fetchAll() with a param like : column, both...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why so many people mess this up:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `where`=:where"); 
$stmt->bindValue(':where', $MyWhere);
$stmt->execute();
$SingleVar = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Make sure that you are selecting a specific `column` in the query and not `*` or you will need to specify the column order number in `fetchColumn()`, example: `$stmt->fetchColumn(2);` That usually isn't a good idea because the columns in the database may be reorganized by, someone...

This will only work properly with `unique 'wheres'`; `fetchColumn()` will not return an array.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get the last insert you add the DESC Limit 1 to the sql statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT `some_col_name` FROM table_name\n"

    . "ORDER BY `some_col_name` DESC\n"

    . "LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//convert the array content to string and store in variable 
$col = implode(" ", $row);
echo $col;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you prepared the statement first? (Before `$stmt->execute()`)

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT some_col_name FROM table_name WHERE user=:user");
```