# PDO query with nested sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have tried using this reference for my select statement but it does not seem to work: [Fetching single row, single column with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666710/fetching-single-row-single-column-with-pdo)

My sql query looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(cost) FROM inventory t1 WHERE t1.`date` = (SELECT max(t2.`date`) FROM inventory t2 WHERE t1.`product` = t2.`product`)";
```

The result should return a single value (the sum of all current costs of products in inventory).

I've tried this with no luck:

```
$stmt=$pdo_dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

Edit: Here is what the table looks like

```
 Table name: inventory
 id | cost | product | date
```

Comment: And what's happening when you execute a query? And `fetch` btw will return at least array or object, not a single value.

Comment: I don't get anything in the result for PHP. When i run the command in mysql client it gives me a result.

Comment: elaborate your question, so people can suggest a better query. A simple join should do the trick generally, can you list table structure along with dummy data ?

Comment: I turned PHP errors on, my db wasn't connecting. Now that I got it connected it seems to give me the result I want. However, as u_mulder mentioned, I'm not sure if fetchColumn would be a better option?