# php PDO object to string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I did a query in mysql that will only return 1 result. which is an Id number. I used PDO::FETCH_OBJ and I got an array that only contain 1 result instead of a string. see below

```
 public function getOrderTerritory($orders_id){
        $this->db->query("
        SELECT 
        territory_id_fk
        FROM orders
        WHERE orders_id = :orders_id");

        //bind method from my database just to prevent some injection. dont mind this
        $this->db->bind(':orders_id', $orders_id);

        //Assign result, the single() is a database method that basically does $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $result = $this->db->single();
        return $result;

    }
```

if I var_dump $result I get

```
object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["territory_id_fk"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

but I only want to see

"2" instead. so I can pass $result to run other methods. right now I am getting array to string conversion error.

Comment: Why you are using PDO::FETCH_OBJ if you need a single column's scalar value?

Comment: I am learning so I dont quite understand all the PDO options yet. is there a PDO::FETCH type that will return string instead?

Comment: Have fun: [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: yes, PDO::FETCH_COLUMN will get you a single column's value, as the name suggests.

Comment: Note that tour database class [suffer from serious design flaw](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#statefulness) and probably other mistakes

Comment: so I should avoid using generic name such as $result for all the query to avoid new query over writing the data from the old query?

Comment: it is not about names. it is about variables. not in this code but in your database class

Comment: Saw you have made a guide on the subject I will check them out right the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching single row, single column with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666710/fetching-single-row-single-column-with-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

after referring to

[Fetching single row, single column with PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666710/fetching-single-row-single-column-with-pdo)

I found `$this->stmt->fetchColumn();` will return a single result as desired.