# Inserting MAX +1 Value into Textbox

Tags: php, html, sql-server, max

I want to  insert MAX +1 value automatically into a read only text input which will then be submitted as an insert query to my database.

I have tested the query in my database and it is the correct query and works fine.

However, when I run it in my program, it returns 1. Not sure if it's returning 1 because it is TRUE or because that is just the value it is getting.

How can I fix this so that I get the correct MAX +1 value?

**SQL/PHP:**

```
<?php

$max = "SELECT MAX(Group_ID) +1 FROM SKU_Group_Dim";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($max);
$result = $stmt->execute();

//echo $result;

?>
```

**Input for max +1 value:**

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" readonly>
```

Comment: What shows `//echo $result;` currently?

Comment: the echoed result is `1` currently

Comment: Have your tried `var_dump($result)` or `print_r($result)`? Then you can see whether it is actually true or just an integer with value 1.

Comment: `mysqli` or `pdo`?

Comment: You have created a race condition here. What happens when two people are using the application? You would be better off using an identity or a sequence to avoid collisions.

Comment: okay, just did `var_dump($result)` and it came out as `bool(true)`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions pdo

Comment: I dont know PhP too well but I have seen this happen when executing nonquery method rather than executescalar...  Also it is likely better to have the ID autogenerated by Sql using identity.  Unless you will only ever have input coming from one process, you will find that the ID conflicts with other processes that are inserting records.

Comment: **An absolutely terrible idea**

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666710/fetching-single-row-single-column-with-pdo

Comment: you need to loop/fetch over successful results. You can't just `echo $result;`.

Comment: Okay so I've gathered this isnt the best way to do things...what would be? Using Ajax that runs a query that selects the max +1?

Comment: you have answers below; see those.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way:

```
$max = "SELECT MAX(Group_ID) +1 FROM SKU_Group_Dim";
$result = $dbh->query($max);
var_dump($result);
```

Because `->execute()` returns only a (bool) see http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php

But you should keep comments, about the logic behind this, from @RiggsFolly and other in mind :)

Comment: This may work but how would I echo the result in the input? Right now if i echo $result in `value=""` then the table that I have and the input box dont load

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Plz go and use `$result` in the right way, if that not comes to your mind be yourself, i dont really now. When you do `var_dump($result);` you will see what you have to do next.  And it is not anymore: `the echoed result is 1 currently`    learn coding for real :-)

Comment: Right now I have `value="<?php echo $result; ?>"` in my input tag...if thats not what I should do, then how should it look? Also this is what the var_dump looks like `object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(42) "SELECT MAX(Group_ID) +1 FROM SKU_Group_Dim" }
`

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Man , plz read the docs (lookup the examples), look for `Return Values`, so you get an `PDOStatement` object, there you have to use an method to get the results. Read it here: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php   Coding is complex

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt->execute()` only yields true of false as the result of the function execution. You need to get the results separately and extract data from result set.

Something like:

```
$stmt->execute()
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $stmt->fetch_row($result);
```

BTW, as mentioned in the comments  **not a very good idea at all** to do this.