# Get SUM of row WHERE date equal

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I am not able to execute the code when doing the SUM of row WHERE date equal to a given date in PHP PDO.
In my case, it calculates all values without considering the date.

MY Code is -

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(`sales_amt`) AS `amazonSales` FROM `sales` WHERE `channel_name` = :channel1 AND `channel_name` = :channel2 AND `inv_date` = :selecteddate");
$stmt->execute(array(':channel1' => 'AMAZON_FBA', ':channel2' => 'AMAZON_IN', ':selecteddate' => '05-09-2020'));
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $amazonSales = $result['amazonSales'];
}
```

DATABASE Table as `sales`

```
---------------------------------------------------
ID   | channel_name  |  sales_amt  |  inv_date    |
---------------------------------------------------
1    | AMAZON_IN     | 10          | 05-09-2020   |
2    | AMAZON_FBA    | 30          | 05-09-2020   |
3    | AMAZON_IN     | 20          | 04-09-2020   |
4    | AMAZON_FBA    | 40          | 05-09-2020   |
5    | AMAZON_IN     | 50          | 03-09-2020   |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I want its output to show `80` same as the issue while fetching total rows also.
Please, help me how to fix this issue and why it comes...

Comment: There is NO row in your table where channel_name = AMAZON_IN and AMAZON_FBA at the same time

Comment: I want it to display sum of both of the case for `Amazon_IN` and `Amazon_FBA`

Comment: surely you simply need to change the `AND` in the where clause to `OR`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT ID, 
       COALESCE(channel_name, 'TOTAL') channel_name, 
       SUM(sales_amt) sales_amt, 
       inv_date
FROM `sales` 
WHERE (   `channel_name` = @channel1 
       OR `channel_name` = @channel2 )
  AND `inv_date` = @selecteddate
GROUP BY ID, 
         channel_name, 
         inv_date 
    WITH ROLLUP
HAVING ID IS NULL 
    OR inv_date IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID IS NULL, ID
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a900e365f988ff3b39cc887da2d82512)

Comment: @JohnCart "not working" is absolutely impossible, and fiddle proves it. If you receive the output which is not safe for YOUR data then you must provide more detailed diagnostic - the best way is to provide a fiddle with YOUR data and define precise point of incorrectness.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the two `channel_name` conditions in parentheses and change the `AND` between them to `OR`, but it would be more concise to use `IN()`.  [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6891b2a7f3095261508eb28899e4963f)

```
SELECT SUM(`sales_amt`)
FROM `sales` 
WHERE `inv_date` = '2020-09-05'
  AND `channel_name` IN ('AMAZON_IN', 'AMAZON_FBA')
// output: 80
```

Code:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare(
    "SELECT SUM(`sales_amt`) AS `amazonSales`
     FROM `sales`
     WHERE `inv_date` = :selecteddate
       AND `channel_name` IN(:channel1, :channel2)"
);
$stmt->execute([
    ':selecteddate' => '05-09-2020',
    ':channel1' => 'AMAZON_FBA',
    ':channel2' => 'AMAZON_IN',
]);
$amazonSales = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Notice that you don't need to alias the `SUM()` value in the `SELECT` clause since `fetchColumn()` doesn't reference the column name that it is fetching.  ([Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1666710/2943403))